# Trying to select by field from different class using foreign key, getting errors

Tags: python, html, django, view

I'm creating a reddit clone as a personal project to get to grips with django, and so far I've got two classes:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Board(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length =100, blank = False)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField('Date Created', auto_now_add=True)
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Notice(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200) #title as it appears on the notice
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False, blank=False)
    posted_on = models.DateTimeField('Posted On', auto_now_add= True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField('Last Updated', auto_now = True)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, null=False)
    isText = models.BooleanField(null=False, blank = False)
    content = models.TextField()
    thumps_up = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    thumps_down = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

And in my urls I have:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<board_name>\w+)/$', views.board_lv)
)
```

What I want to do is have the url pattern compare against the "name" field in the "Board" model using the "board" foreign key in the "Notice" model, and then open up a page listing all the notices with in that board (similar to subreddits in reddit).

**I'm getting a type error saying** "Notice object is not iterable", which leads me to think I've only got one object instead of a list, but I shouldn't have should I?

The iteration is in this part of the noticeList.html file;

```
{% for n in latest_notices %}
    <li>
    {% if not n.isText %} 
        <h2><a href="{{ n.content }}">{{ n.title }}</a></h2>            
    {% else %}
        <h2>{{ n.title }}</h2>
        <p>{{ n.content }}</p>
    {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

where the views are:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from notices.models import Board, Notice

def index(request):
    latest_notices = Notice.objects.order_by('-posted_on')
    context = {'latest_notices': latest_notices}
    return render(request, 'noticeList.html', context)

def board_lv(request, board_name):
    latest_notices = get_object_or_404(Notice, board__name=board_name)
    context = {'latest_notices': latest_notices}
    return render(request, 'noticeList.html', context)
```

Also, in the error traceback, the board_name variable value is preceded by a 'u' before the quoted string, e.g:

```
Variable        Value
board_name      u'worldnews'
```

If I'm getting the url pattern wrong or haven't explained the problem well enough, please let me know as any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: full traceback error

```
Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  115.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/adnan/Documents/django-noticeboard/noticeboard/notices/views.py" in board_lv
  13.   return render(request, 'noticeList.html', context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/django/shortcuts/__init__.py" in render
  53.     return HttpResponse(loader.render_to_string(*args, **kwargs),
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  177.         return t.render(context_instance)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
  140.             return self._render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in _render
  134.         return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  284.                 return nodelist.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/base.py" in render
  830.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/debug.py" in render_node
  74.             return node.render(context)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Django-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  147.             values = list(values)

Exception Type: TypeError at /b/worldnews/
Exception Value: 'Notice' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Please show the full error traceback (click "switch to cut-and-past view" first if you're getting it from the 500 page).

Comment: @DanielRoseman will do, do you want the template error too? It only highlights the first line i've given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `get_object_or_404(Notice, board__name=board_name)` returns one `Notice` model instance and it's not iterable.

One possible solution is to add this to a list and pass to the context:

```
def board_lv(request, board_name):
    latest_notices = get_object_or_404(Notice, board__name=board_name)
    context = {'latest_notices': [latest_notices]}
    return render(request, 'noticeList.html', context)
```

UPD for the next error: then, don't use `get_object_or_404` if there could be more than one `Notice`s per board. Use `filter`:

```
def board_lv(request, board_name):
    latest_notices = Notice.objects.filter(board__name=board_name)
    context = {'latest_notices': latest_notices}
    return render(request, 'noticeList.html', context)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Ahh that worked, thanks a lot!

Edit: Ok, so now I'm getting another error, it only seems to work when theres only one notice object for that board. I tried it with a board that has multiple notices and now I get a multipleobjectsreturned error!